# How can I schedule a child activity to execute *before* the parent is completed?

Tags: .net-4.5, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I have a WF (4.5) workflow activity that creates a child workflow (evaluating a VisualBasicValue expression). I need the result **before** I complete the parent workflow.

I add the expression to the metadata like this:

```
private VisualBasicValue<string> _expression;

protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
{
    base.CacheMetadata(metadata); 
    var visualBasicValue = (VisualBasicValue<string>)(_childActivity.Text.Expression);
    var expressionText = visualBasicValue.ExpressionText;
    _expression = new VisualBasicValue<string>(expressionText);
    metadata.AddChild(_expression);
}
```

I tried scheduling the activity in the Execute method like this:

```
protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
{
    context.ScheduleActivity(context, _expression, OnCompleted);
    Result.Set(context, _value);
}
```

With a callback of:

```
private void OnCompleted(NativeActivityContext context, ActivityInstance completedInstance, string result)
{
    _value = result;
}
```

Unfortunately, the _expression activity is only executed **after** the parent's execution method returns. Adding it as an implementation child doesn't work (it cannot work as an implementation child, as it is supposed to evaluate an expression that contains variables external to the parent).

Any ideas how to overcome this and execute within the execution context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a few days but I managed to resolve my own issue (without breaking the normal of how WF works).

What I ended up doing is, using reflection, iterated over the child's properties and created a [LinkedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) of evaluation expressions (using [VisualBasicValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782058.aspx)) of each of its arguments, in the **CacheMetadata** method. Then in the execution phase, I scheduled the execution of the first evaluation. In its callback I iterate over the remaining evaluations, scheduling the execution of the next evaluations, adding the result to a dictionary, until its done.

Finally, if there are no more evaluations to schedule, I schedule a *final activity* that takes the dictionary as its argument, and can do whatever it wants with it. Upon *its own*, it optionally returns the final result to the container's OutArgument.

What I previously failed to understand, is that even though the scheduling occurs after the instantiating activity's execution, the callback runs before control is returned to the host workflow application, and in that space I could work.

Answer (score 1):

In code, as in real life, you can't schedule something to the past (yet :).

`ScheduleActivity()` will place the activity within an execution queue and execute it as soon as it can. As the parent activity is still running, _*expression* will only execute after it. Bottom-line, it's an asynchronous call.

If you want to control when _*expression* is called, just use [WorkflowInvoker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowinvoker.aspx) to execute it, synchronously, whenever you want.

```
public class MyNativeActivity : NativeActivity
{
    private readonly VisualBasicValue<string> _expression;

    public MyNativeActivity()
    {
        // 'expression' construction logic goes here
        _expression = new VisualBasicValue<string>("\"Hi!\"");
    }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        var _value = WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(_expression);

        Console.WriteLine("Value returned by '_expression': " + _value);

        // use '_value' for something else...
    }
}
```

Comment: I missed your last paragraph. Obviously this won't work if you need to execute it within the context. I can't remember another good solution. It's always difficult to say this when I don't have your context but my guess is that you should take a step back. If you end up here, something is inherently wrong with the implementation.

Comment: The problem that I'm trying to solve is that I need to take a child activity, and rather than executing it, I need to parse it (including evaluating the child's properties), and run another process on it. For example, rather than running a compiler activity (in TFS), run another compiler, with the same properties.

Comment: And why won't you take the logic from the "child activity" and place it in a separate activity that you can call whenever you need that expression evaluated. Again, it seems you're taking the wrong approach and instead of fix it from the beginning you're trying to remedy something that can't be.

Comment: Taking *your* approach, I can think of a couple of other solutions. 1) use [DynamicActivity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.dynamicactivity(v=vs.110).aspx) to build your "context" through [DynamicActivity.Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.dynamicactivity.properties(v=vs.110).aspx). 2) Use [Assign](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647739(v=vs.110).aspx) activity in conjunction with VisualBasicReference and VisualBasicValue (the visual designer does that for you, if you're using it). This all sounds code smell to me :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about taking the logic from the child activity - it is out of my control (e.g. MSBuild, MSTest from TFS-build).

Comment: I'll look into the DynamicActivity, thanks. Could you explain however what your second option is? I'm not sure that I understand how the Assign helps (I use the visual designer. The container activity is supposed to allow a user to drag an MSBuild activity, and the container will replace it with its own logic).

Comment: I'm not familiar with TFS activities so I don't known where your control starts and ends. From what I can infer what you're doing is no more than _assign_ a __value_ to a variable for then to use it in some way. Why can't you use Assign activity before? For the 'To' argument goes a new workflow variable (lets call it _ValueVar_) and 'Value' takes that `_childActivity.Text.Expression` (whatever that is). Assign activity will evaluate that expression for you, using _VisualBasicValue_ internally. From then on you can pass _ValueVar_ to other activities, the way you want.

Comment: Sorry if I'm saying something obvious, that you already tried or simply can't be done on your context. From the outside it seems you're trying to do many things in just one place when you can break that thing down in a bunch of smaller steps. PS: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284703/wf4-how-do-i-evaluate-an-expression-only-known-at-runtime)